# Link loaded into my gridview try to navigate to my local server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm loading links into a gridview, but if they aren't appended with http:// it goes to my server. So something like www.yahoo.com when clicked would go to http://localhost:1304/.../controls/www.yahoo.com. How would I make the browser open a new window to whatever is in the link field when clicked besides doing string manipulation.

I've tried both asp:hyperlinkfield and templatefields

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link"> 
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<% #(Eval("Link")) %>' NavigateUrl='<% #Eval("Link") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

    <%--<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Link" HeaderText="Link" SortExpression="Link" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="Link" Target="_blank" />--%>
```

Here is some source from the page. The comcast link appends itself to a local destination while the yahoo one is fine.

```
<td>15478963</td><td>test data - comcast</td><td><a href="Controls/www.comcast.net" target="_blank">www.comcast.net</a></td><td align="right">12/23/2009</td><td>Justen</td>
            </tr><tr style="color:Black;background-color:Gainsboro;">
                <td>12345678</td><td>Update works!</td><td><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">http://www.yahoo.com</a></td><td align="right">12/23/2009</td><td>Justen</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior (appending the url to the end of your local server) is caused by the way URL's are interpreted by browsers. To redirect to www.yahoo.com, for example, you have to use an *absolute* URL, starting with **http://**.

If your links are pointing to addresses which don't start with **http://**, then the browser interprets them as *relative* urls, in relation to the present (local server) location.

So you'll have to do some string manipulation, to check whether the address starts with **http://** and add it when it's necessary. Maybe you could do it in the `OnRowDataBound` event handler for the GridView

Also, to make the links open a new window (or tab) in the browser, you should use the `target="_blank"` attribute, as pointed out in the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `target="_blank"` attribute to the link. This will open any link in a new window.

See the href [target attribute](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/values.html#frametarget) documentation.

Comment: That doesn't work. I've already tried it (it's in my code I posted) in the asp:hyperlinkfield, and I just now tried in the template and the same error occurs

Comment: What is the error that occurs? Can you post the code that is generated (view source in the browser)?

Comment: The error that it is appending the url to the end of a local server location instead of just by itself. I've updated my original post with some source from the page

Comment: Looks like an error in your `Link` property/method. Can you post the code for that?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The datagrid is being pop'd by a LINQ datasource and Link is coming from a table. The only method it has is to save what the customer enters into a txt box into a database with no alterations be done to it.

Comment: Have you checked what is returned by the LINQ query in all cases?